Выбрать лучшие перекрытия интервалов
У меня есть список из нескольких взвешенных интервалов - это кортежи (value, start, stop):
#   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
# 1         [___]                           
# 2 [___________________________________]   
# 3 [_______]                               
# 8     [_______________________]           
# 7                     [___________________]
# 6                                 [___]   
# 4     [_______________________]           

# input
# (value: float, start: float, stop: float)
list_in = [(2, 0, 9), (3, 0, 2), (8, 1, 7), (4, 1, 7), (1, 3, 4), (5, 5, 10), (6, 8, 9)]

Я хочу найти все частичные перекрытия и выбрать из них "лучший", то есть, с наибольшим value.
Для моего примера правильный ответ:
#   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
# 1                                         
# 2                                         
# 3 [___]                                   
# 8     [_______________________]           
# 7                             [___________]
# 6                                         
# 4                                         

# output
list_out = [(3, 0, 1), (8, 1, 7), (7, 7, 10)]

Я постараюсь не усложнять всеми условиями, которые у меня есть, но вот минимум из того что вы должны знать:

Входной массив кортежей никак не отсортирован
У меня есть реализация дерева интервалов, если алгоритм производительнее или проще с ним - используйте его

3) Нужно учитывать -float('inf') для начала интервала и float('inf') для конца интервала.

Если значение value у обоих интервалов совпадает, то лучше тот - который короче. Если при этом они одинаковы по длинне, то это точная копия интервала - игнорируйте точные копии.
Игнорируйте интервалы, у которых start == stop

Если это упростит вам задачу, то вот все возможные кейсы взаимного расположения интервалов:
    # All cases for two intervals:
    #    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
    #                   [______________]               
    #                                                  
    #  1 [_________]    |              |                 altc_altd_bltc_bltd
    #  2      [_________]              |                 altc_altd_beqc_bltd
    #  3           [_________]         |                 altc_altd_bgtc_bltd
    #  4                [_________]    |                 aeqc_altd_bgtc_bltd
    #  5                |     [___]    |                 agtc_altd_bgtc_bltd
    #  6                [______________]                 aeqc_altd_bgtc_beqd
    #  7           [___________________]                 altc_altd_bgtc_beqd
    #  8           [________________________]            altc_altd_bgtc_bgtd
    #  9                [___________________]            aeqc_altd_bgtc_bgtd
    # 10                |    [_________]                 agtc_altd_bgtc_beqd
    # 11                |         [_________]            agtc_altd_bgtc_bgtd
    # 12                |              [_________]       agtc_aeqb_bgtc_bgtd
    # 13                |              |    [_________]  agtc_agtd_bgtc_bgtd    

Все кейсы для интервала и точки:
value, start, stop = interval
point = x

point < start
point == start
start < point and point < stop
point == stop
stop < point

Любые мои попытки решить эту задачу "в лоб" вызывают комбинаторный взрыв и превращают код в callback hell
Пожалуйста, помогите. ЗЫ: я могу вставить свою попытку, но она занимает 200 строк кода.

Благодаря ответу @StanislavVolodarskiy, я смог упростить код до следующего:
import heapq
from typing import Callable, Optional


__all__ = ['DataInterval', 'inlay_right_to_left', 'inlay_data_intervals', 'TestInlayTwoWeigtedIntervals']

class DataInterval(object):
    _identifier_counter = 0
    
    def __init__(self, weight, start, stop) -> None:
        self._identifier = self._identifier_counter
        self._identifier_counter += 1
        
        self.data: float = weight
        self.start: float = start
        self.stop: float = stop
    
    @property
    def identifier(self):
        return self._identifier
    
    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self._identifier == other._identifier
        
        return False
    
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self._identifier)

def inlay_data_intervals(intervals: list[DataInterval], key: Optional[Callable[[DataInterval], float]]=None):
    if key is None:
        key: Callable[[DataInterval], float] = lambda interval: (interval.data, interval.start, interval.stop)
    
    precomputed_values = []
    
    # event queue
    # list[(x, is_end, index)]
    events: list[tuple] = []
    for index, interval in enumerate(intervals):
        precomputed_values.append(key(interval))
        events.append((interval.start, False, index))
        events.append((interval.stop, True, index))
    
    events.sort()
    
    # status
    deleted = [False] * (len(events) // 2)
    heap = []

    # print
    last_start = None
    last_index = None

    for x, is_end, index in events:
        # update status
        if is_end:
            deleted[index] = True
        else:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (precomputed_values[index], index))

        # remove deleted items from heap top
        while len(heap) > 0 and deleted[heap[0][1]]:
            heapq.heappop(heap)

        current_value, current_index = heap[0] if len(heap) > 0 else (None, None)
        last_value = precomputed_values[last_index] if last_index is not None else None
        if current_value != last_value:
            if last_index is not None and last_start < x:
                yield DataInterval(intervals[last_index].data, last_start, x)
            
            last_start = x
            last_index = current_index


Также есть Тесты
Громоздко, но я не разобрался как заставить VS Code видеть параметризованные тесты.

Алгоритмически: 1) Выбираем все точки (начала, концы, всё единым списком) и строим все минимальные (не имеющие точек внутри) интервалы; 2) Для каждого минимального интервала выбираем все перекрывающие его, и определяем максимальный вес среди них; 3) Обрабатываем список и сливаем соседние интервалы с одинаковым весом в один большой.

Да, я понимаю этот алгоритм, проблема в том, что написать его с учётом всех случаев, эффективно и чисто у меня почему-то не получается :D

@Akina моя изначальная идея была написать функцию, которая разбивает два интервала, учитывая все случаи, а потом сделать reduce  по списку, но это не сработало, потому что иногда один интервал поглощает два и больше интервалов, я просто не могу сообразить как сделать такую сложную редукцию.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=заметание

Ну я ж вроде всё расписал, и достаточно подробно. И я вообще не понимаю, какие "все случаи" нужно учитывать.

Вторая идея заключается в том, чтобы взять первый интервал из списка и рассечь его со вторым интервалом из списка, а затем взять третий интервал и рассечь уже им. Но я не могу понять, как написать такую функцию рассечения. Её сигнатура была бы: split_by_intersections(accumulator: list[tuple[float, float, float]], interval: tuple[float, float, float]) -> list[tuple[float, float, float]]. Такую функцию уже можно было бы использовать с functools.reduce.

@Akina в вопросе перечислены 10 случаев взаимного расположения интервалов * 4 случая, учитывающих -float('inf')/float('inf') на концах интервалов * 3 случая сравнения value (<, ==, >) * 3 случая сравнения left.stop - left.start и right.stop - right.start (<, ==, >). Итого 10 * 4 * 3 * 3 = 360. Конечно, не все комбинации следует рассматривать, но полный список состоит из 360 ветвей алгоритма и это только для двух интервалов.

Не влияет от слова "вообще".

@StanislavVolodarskiy я осматривал эти вопросы. В моём случае задача усложняется весом каждого интервала, но спасибо за ваше время

Какой смысл сравнивать равные по значению интервалы ещё и по длине, если в ответе остаётся только значение?

@StanislavVolodarsky Потому что интервалы являются частью более сложной сущности. До кортежей я их упростил, потому что вопрос и так очень сложен для stackoverflow и вызывает недопонимания.

@StanislavVolodarskiy грубо говоря, это интегралы. То есть (2, 3, 7) означает, что некая характеристика 2.0 распространяется на протяжении числовой прямой от числа 3.0 до числа 7.0. Соответственно, эта характеристика слабее, чем (2, 3, 6), но сильнее, чем (2, 3, 8) потому что 2./(8.-3.) <  2./(7.-3.) < 2./(6.-3.). И кроме того, эта сущность, как я сказал, не ограничивается 3 числами, у меня есть и другие критерии сраанения. Я упростил задачу до минимально воспроизводимого примера, как указано в рекомендациях stackoverflow. И я указал, что это упрощение в вопросе.

@StanislavVolodarskiy пожалуйста, придерживайтесь изначально заданного вопроса, а не комментария. Я дал комментарий исключительно, чтобы удовлетворить ваше любопытство и уточнить свою мотивацию в постановке вопроса. Я видел ваш ответ, выглядит многообещающим. Я смогу опробовать его в понедельник.

Тогда замените веса на кортежи и сведите задачу к предыдущей. То есть, кортежи (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 8) заменяются на ((2, 1/(7-3)), 3, 7), ((2, 1/(6-3)), 3, 6), ((2, 1/(8-3)), 3, 8). Кортежи в Питоне упорядочены лексикографически, вы получите нужный результат без усложнения алгоритмов.

@StanislavVolodarskiy нет, я не буду менять вопрос. Он останется как и был.

Задача решается заметанием. События - концы интервалов. Очередь событий - сортированный массив, при равных временах начала отрезков сортируются до концов. Статус: множество отрезков, покрывающих данную точку. Структура для множества - максимальная куча значений, поддерживающая удаление элементов.
Обработка события:

если это начало отрезка, добавить его значение в множество
если это конец отрезка, пометить его удалённым в множестве

Для печати результата хранится начало текущего максимума (если оно есть) и сам текущий максимум. Если максимум изменился в этом событии,

печатается тройка (максимум, начало, текущее событие);
обновляется начало и текущий максимум.

import heapq


def min_values(intervals):
    # event queue
    events = [] # (x, is_end, index, value, label)
    for index, (start, stop, value, label) in enumerate(intervals):
        events.append((start, False, index, value, label))
        events.append((stop , True , index, value, label))
    events.sort()

    # status
    deleted = [False] * (len(events) // 2)
    heap = []

    # print
    last_start = None
    last_value = None
    last_label = None

    for x, is_end, index, value, label in events:
        # update status
        if is_end:
            deleted[index] = True
        else:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (value, index, label))

        # remove deleted items from heap top
        while heap and deleted[heap[0][1]]:
            heapq.heappop(heap)
        
        # print
        value = heap[0][0] if heap else None
        label = heap[0][2] if heap else None
        if value != last_value:
            if last_value is not None and last_start < x:
                yield last_label, last_start, x 
            last_start = x
            last_value = value
            last_label = label


def max_values(intervals):
    return min_values(
        (start, stop, (-value, stop - start), value)
        for value, start, stop in intervals
    )


def test():
    for intervals, expected in (
        # value left > value right
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 3, 6)], [(2, 3, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 0, 2)], [(1, 0, 2), (2, 3, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 1, 3)], [(1, 1, 3), (2, 3, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 2, 4)], [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 3, 5)], [(2, 3, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5)], [(2, 3, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 5, 7)], [(2, 3, 6), (1, 6, 7)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 6, 8)], [(2, 3, 6), (1, 6, 8)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 7, 9)], [(2, 3, 6), (1, 7, 9)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (1, 2, 7)], [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 6), (1, 6, 7)]),
        
        # value left == value right
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 6)], [(2, 3, 6)]), # is copy
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 0, 2)], [(2, 0, 2), (2, 3, 6)]), # 2. / (6. - 3.) < 2. / (2. - 0.)
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 1, 3)], [(2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 6)]), # 2. / (6. - 3.) < 2. / (3. - 1.)
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 2, 4)], [(2, 2, 4), (2, 4, 6)]), # 2. / (6. - 3.) < 2. / (4. - 2.)
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 5)], [(2, 3, 5), (2, 5, 6)]), # 2. / (6. - 3.) < 2. / (5. - 3.)
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5)], [(2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 5), (2, 5, 6)]), # 2. / (6. - 3.) < 2. / (5. - 4.)
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 5, 7)], [(2, 3, 5), (2, 5, 7)]), # 2. / (6. - 3.) < 2. / (7. - 5.)
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 6, 8)], [(2, 3, 6), (2, 6, 8)]), # 2. / (6. - 3.) < 2. / (8. - 6.)
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 7, 9)], [(2, 3, 6), (2, 7, 9)]), # 2. / (6. - 3.) < 2. / (9. - 7.)
        ([(2, 3, 6), (2, 2, 7)], [(2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 6), (2, 6, 7)]), # 2. / (6. - 3.) > 2. / (7. - 2.)
        
        # value left < value right
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 3, 6)], [(3, 3, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 0, 2)], [(3, 0, 2), (2, 3, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 1, 3)], [(3, 1, 3), (2, 3, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 2, 4)], [(3, 2, 4), (2, 4, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 3, 5)], [(3, 3, 5), (2, 5, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 4, 5)], [(2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (2, 5, 6)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 5, 7)], [(2, 3, 5), (3, 5, 7)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 6, 8)], [(2, 3, 6), (3, 6, 8)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 7, 9)], [(2, 3, 6), (3, 7, 9)]),
        ([(2, 3, 6), (3, 2, 7)], [(3, 2, 7)]),
    ):
        actual = list(max_values(intervals))
        if actual != expected:
            print(intervals, expected, actual)


test()


Спасибо! Посмотрю как буду дома

Это очень хороший алгоритм, я отмечу его как ответ, но постараюсь учесть float('inf') на концах отрезков и протестирую его для неочевидных кейсов.

@StanislaVolodarskiy я уточнил вопрос и прикрепил файл с подобием тестов без лишних зависимостей. Это позволит быстро проверить, соответствует ли ваш пример условиям вопроса. Пожалуйста, напишите, если что-то не так.

Ваше решение не учитывает некоторые кейсы. С 12 по 17 и 19 (всего 30 кейсов, они добавлены в вопрос).

Подогнал решение под тесты.

@StanislaVolodarskiy Огонь, спасибо!

Показываю на исходных данных.
Шаг 1-1. Сбор точек. После него получаем массив
0,1,2,3,5,7,8,9,10

Шаг 1-2. Конвертация в минимальные интервалы. Получаем набор
0-1
1-2
2-3
3-5
5-7
7-8
8-9
9-10

Шаг 2. Для каждого интервала подбираем перекрывающие их исходные интервалы, собираем веса, выбираем максимальный









0-1
веса 2,3


1-2
веса 2,3,8,4


2-3
веса 1,2,8,4


3-5
веса 2,8,4


5-7
веса 2,8,7,4


7-8
веса 2,7


8-9
веса 2,7,6


9-10
веса 7



Шаг 3. Объединяем соседние интервалы, если их веса равны. Получаем










0-1
веса 2,3
ИТОГО 0-1 вес 3


1-2
веса 2,3,8,4



2-3
веса 1,2,8,4



3-5
веса 2,8,4



5-7
веса 2,8,7,4
ИТОГО 1-7 вес 8


7-8
веса 2,7



8-9
веса 2,7,6



9-10
веса 7
ИТОГО 7-10 вес 7




Если я правильно понял ваш алгоритм, то для случая [(5, 0, 1), (5, 3, 4)] он выдаст три интервала. При всём уважении, я не понимаю как реализовать шаг 2. Я сейчас добавляю в вопрос все возможные случаи для двух интервалов. Это действительно может быть гораздо более сложной задачей, чем кажется на первый взгляд.

Однако, спасибо за ваше время, я поставил "+" ответу.

Сложность алгоритма O(N^2) если искать интервалы для точек перебором. O(N*log(N)) - если искать с помощью дерева интервалов, но я дома попробую в нём разобраться подробнее, потому что я ещё его не совсем понял.

@Aycon какой перебор? Предварительно отсортировать. А ниже n*logn всё одно не опуститься. Если я правильно понял ваш алгоритм, то для случая [(5, 0, 1), (5, 3, 4)] он выдаст три интервала. Да, именно так. Причём интервал (1,3) будет с нулевым весом.

да, согласен. Это минимум.

Правильно будет если он выдаст 2 исходных интервала, потому что они не пересекаются и между ними разрыв  [(5, 0, 1), (5, 3, 4)]. В исходных данных есть интервалы с любым числовым весом (в том числе с нулевым), но есть промежутки, где нет интервалов, мне это нужно учесть.

@Aycon Ну и что? Деление на точки даст 4 точки, то есть три интервала. Средний даст нулевой вес, ибо там нет исходных интервалов. нулевой вес - отсутствие этого интервала в ответе (и, кстати, их можно не объединять - всё одно выбрасывать). Всё ровно.

При всём уважении, это бизнес логика. Мне нужно два интервала на этом примере потому что они не пересекаются. Если после расчёта у меня будет 3 интервала, то эта часть кода работает неправильно. Я удаляю копии, с учётом приоритета. Тут не должно быть 3 интервала. И вы не можете просто задать ему value = 0, потому что это произвольное число.

@Aycon Ну так в итоге и получится два интервала. На шаге 1-2 сформируются 3, но один будет выброшен на шаге 2 (или 3) по причине нулевого веса. Останутся два. Не, не нравится ноль - ну используйте Inf. Или что там заведомо не может быть в весах... всё равно это не вес, а маркер отсутствия.

Нет, так не пойдёт.

ну нет так нет..

Этот алгоритм не работает, например, для входа [(8, 1, 5), (7, 1, 3), (7, 3, 5)

@Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA С чего бы? Три точки (1, 3, 5), два интервала (1-3, 3-5), соотв. веса ((1-3 : 8, 7), (3-5 : 7, 7)), результат (1-3 вес 8, 3-5 вес 7). Что не так-то?

Во-первых, ваш алгоритм дает другой ответ, для 3-5 есть вес 8. Так что ответ у вас получается 1-5 вес 8. Или я что-то не понял. В моем понимании задачи ответ на таких входных данных это (1-3 вес 7, 3-5 вес 7). Если у вас все же получается, как вы написали, то тоже проблема. Я понимаю условие так, что в результате должны быть только интервалы из входного множества интервалов, а у вас алгорим разбивает, а значит в ответе может получится, то чего не было на входе. В данном случае, во входном множестве нет интервала 1-3 с весом 8, значит и результате не должно быть.

@Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Да, я плохо посмотрел... меня сбивает с толку. что сначала идёт характеристика, и только потом координаты. Так что моим алгоритмом, вы правы, получается так: Три точки (1, 3, 5), два интервала (1-3, 3-5), соотв. веса ((1-3 : 8, 7), (3-5 : 8, 7)), сырой результат (1-3 вес 8, 3-5 вес 8), окончательный результат (1-5 вес 8).
